# Android update doesn't appear in play store

Tags: android, google-play-services, release, publish, release-management

From last 2 days I'm submitting new App-bundle/apks in GooglePlayStore and Release section is shows me like this: [image]

but whenever I click url to open app, it shows me old app to download rather than new version. 
[image]

What should I consider?

Rather than de-voting, there's a better way to answer.
Thanks to all of you guys.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this too. The play store page has been displaying this banner now:

> Due to adjusted work schedules at this time, we are currently experiencing longer than usual review times.
>   Please expect review times of 7 days or longer.

If you install the Play Console developer app and go to your app's listing there you can see a more informative notice that says "Update pending", but this is not clearly shown on the web page for some reason.

[image: App notice banner]

Update: On the Play Console the status is now in small text under the app name. If you go to the "Dashboard" page you should see something like this (which says "Processing update"):

[image: Play Console dashboard]

Comment: I can't believe this isn't listed on the web. How hard can it be to display a simple status stating that the update is pending. Wasted a lot of time on this. Thanks for the tip about the google play developer console app:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer from Google regarding our issue:

[image: Android Support]